# Unique lists from list of lists where first and last values are fixed Python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists; each list has a prescribed first and last value. For each first and last value combination I would like to find the total number of unique lists. Uniqueness is defined such that there can be no duplication of elements in the middle of the list (between first and last values) between lists with the same first and last value combination.

For example, for the following list of lists;

```
[[2, 5, 7, 12], [2, 5, 10, 12], [2, 3, 12], [3, 34, 4, 6], [3, 4, 6]]
```

There are 2 first and last value combinations: [2,...,12] and [3,...,6].
One set of unique lists would be:

```
[[2, 5, 7, 12], [2, 3, 12], [3, 34, 4, 6]]
```

Other combinations of unique lists are possible, however I am only concerned with the number of unique lists. For the example above there are 2 unique lists for the combination [2,...,12] and 1 unique list for the combination [3,...,6].

What would be the best way to do this in python?

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way is to index all lists by their first and last values, then filter these.

You could do that by adding all those lists to a dictionary with all the keys being `(first, last)` tuples. Then you would go over each one of these and remove duplicates.

A quick example:

```
mapping = defaultdict(list)
for item in target_lists:
   mapping[item[0], item[-1]].append(item)

for k, items in mapping.iteritems():
   mapping[k] = [some_filter_function(v) for v in items]
```

You have to modify this a bit to set your condition to decide if it's a duplicate or not (I'm not sure I understood your criteria).

Hope it helps!

**Update**:

I think I understood your criteria. What you have to do, is keep track of which elements in the lists appear more than once. And then you go through the lists, checking against that record you made (which are recorded only once) if there are elements which should not be there. If there are, you discard that element. One way to do this is similar to this:

```
for k, items in mapping.iteritems():
    count_item = defaultdict(int)
    for item in items:
        for i in item[1:-1]:
            count_item[i] += 1
    mapping[k] = [item for item in items if all(count_item[i] == 1 for i in item[1:-1])]
```

That's one of the ways to do it. But I'm almost sure that you will have to make 2 loops: one to check which are the elements to reject, and one to do the actual filtering. The implementation might differ.

Comment: many thanks for your suggestion, dictionary works well. I am still struggling with the filter_function though. My criteria is as follows: a unique list (for a given first and last combination) is one where any of the middle elements (between first and last elements) are not found in any other list of the same (first and last combination). I hope that that is clearer.

Comment: @scott_ouce I updated my answer. The way it was (in a separate function) you would have to pass it the list you are processing too, and it would be less efficient because you would need to *each time* check through all the other items, instead of doing it once. I hope I make sense :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this, using a defaultdict to track the head+tail IDs, and sets to tally unique entries:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [[2, 5, 7, 12], [2, 5, 10, 12], [2, 3, 12], [3, 34, 4, 6], [3, 4, 6]]
dic = defaultdict(lambda: set())
for item in a:
    dic[(item[0], item[-1])].add(tuple(item[1:-1]))

for id, variants in dic.items():
     print "ID %s: %i unique entries" % (str(id), len(variants))
```

Comment: many thanks for your suggestion. The dictionary works well to manage the head+tail, but my criteria for selecting a 'unique' list is not handled using a simple set. Instead, my criteria is as follows: a unique list (for a given head+tail combination) is one where any of the middle elements (between head+tail IDs) are not found in any other list of the same (Head+tail combination). I hope that that is clearer